# Why is the class attribute changing only once?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Battlefield:
    def __init__(self):
        self.field = new_battlefield()
        self.amount_ships = 0
        self.ships = []
        self.fourdeck = []
        self.tripledecks = []
        self.doubledecks = []
        self.singledecks = []

    def change_value(self, point, value):
        if '\n' in self.field[point]:
            self.field[point] = ' {}\n'.format(value)
        else:
            self.field[point] = ' {}'.format(value)

    def make_move(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return '    a b c d e f g h i j\n\n' + \
               ''.join(self.field.values())
```

Battlefield.field is dictionary with keys:

```
1  1a 1b 1c 1d 1e 1f 1g 1h 1i 1j
2  2a 2b 2c 2d
3  ..
4  ..
5  ..
6  ..
7  ..
8  ..
9  ..
10 10a 10b 10c 10d 10e 10f 10g 10h 10j
```

I know that this is far from the best solution, but to work with this, I decided to write a cursor class:

```
class Cursor:
    def __init__(self, start_point=None):
        self.battlefield = Battlefield()
        self.field_keys = list(self.battlefield.field.keys())
        if start_point is not None:
            self.point = start_point
        else:
            self.point = '1a'
        self.battlefield.change_value(self.point, 'X')
        self.point_key_idx = self.field_keys.index(self.point)


    def up(self):
        if self.point_key_idx not in range(1, 11):
            new_point_key = self.point_key_idx - 11
            self.point = self.field_keys[new_point_key]
        return self.point

    def down(self):
        pass

    def left(self):
        pass

    def right(self):
        pass

    def move(self, move):
        if move in ('up', 'down', 'left', 'right'):
            self.battlefield.change_value(self.point, '~')
            new_point = self.__getattribute__(move)()
            self.battlefield.change_value(new_point, 'X')
        else:
            raise ValueError('Move must be in: up, down, left, right.')

        return new_point
```

**My problem:**
When I try to move a cursor multiple times by using the "up" function and others, the self.point value changes only once.

```
cur = Cursor('4d')
print(cur.point) # 4d

cur.up()
print(cur.point) # 3d

cur.up()
print(cur.point) # 3d

cur.up()
print(cur.point) # 3d
```

The last use a function should return "1d". I dont know what to do..

Comment: What is `self.point_key_idx` after each operation?

Comment: `up()` only changes `self.point` when `self.point_key_idx` is not between 1 and 10. I guess after the first `up()` it's in that range, so it doesn't change it any more.

Comment: FYI, the normal way to access attributes dynamically is with `getattr(self, move)`

Comment: self.point_key_idx - index of point in list of battlefield dictionary keys @Barmar

Comment: Thanks for the advice on gettattr. Now I will use it @Barmar

Comment: range(1, 11) does not allow making a move if the cursor reaches the edge of the field.I checked your guess. This is not a problem @Barmar

Comment: It's not clear what `Battlefield.field` is. Are 1, 2, 3, ... included in the keys? Although recent versions of Python remember key order, it's not a good idea to depend on it, so indexing `self.field_keys` seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, 1-10 its also keys. In the future I will make the ordered dict. I know the normal solution is a nested array. The dictionary solution initially only brings troubles, but I only want to rewrite the existing logic in oop style @Barmar

Comment: I still don't understand how `up()` is using that dictionary. Could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: It seems like you're really complicating it by using the dictionary rather than a list of lists.

Comment: Then `cur.point` could just be a `(row, column)` tuple.

Comment: I'm very stubborn and not very smart))) But that doesn't really apply to my problem with the Cursor class @Barmar

Comment: I'd really like to help you, you need to post enough information for me to figure out what's happening. What is the actual value of `Battlefield.field`? Have you tried adding print statements to the code to see what's happening?

Comment: Yes, i did. Point before: 4d Point after: 3d,3d,3d,3d Same with move('up'). Same if look at battlefield.field with "X" where point is located. Same in functions like "up" after if operator @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only updating `self.point`, not `self.point_key_idx`.

```
    def up(self):
        if self.point_key_idx not in range(1, 11):
            self.point_key_idx -= 11
            self.point = self.field_keys[self.point_key_idx]
        return self.point
```